# CSS Radio-Boxes do nothing

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I´ve got a problem with my Web-Design: I want content box to open when a specific radio button is activated with

```
input#topic1:checked ~ #content1{
color:yellow;
}
```

but nothing happens. Rest of code is in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/wzm4xtzg/) jsfiddle. I bet the answer is really easy but I tried a lot and didn´t found any question which answeres this.

Thanks for any effords

Tim

Comment: you don't need to close `input` tags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `~` selector works with siblings that share the same parent, in your case the parent is `body` but the content divs are inside `label`, so you should target it like this:

```
input#topic1:checked ~ label #content1 {
  color: yellow;
}

input#topic2:checked ~ label #content2 {
  color: yellow;
}

input#topic3:checked ~ label #content3 {
  color: yellow;
}
```

See jsFiddle fork: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/k8gxzq56/

Answer (score 1):

First you don't have to close input tags as sais @Aziz

Then, I use javascript to do this.

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wzm4xtzg/1/)

```
$(function(){
    $("input[type=radio]").on('click', function(){
    $('.contentbox').removeClass('yellow');
    // get the target link
    target = $(this).data('href');
    $("#"+target).addClass('yellow');
  });
});
```

Comment: you have two solutions right now but I think @Aziz is better because it's only CSS ;)

Answer (score 0):

Rearranged your code to make it work with CSS only.

```css
.contentbox{
 width:100vw;
 height:10vw;
}
#content1{
 background:#0000FF;
}
#content2{
 background:#FF0000;
}
#content3{
 background:#00FF00;
}

input#topic1:checked + .content1{
 color:yellow;
}
input#topic2:checked + .content2{
 color:yellow;
}
input#topic3:checked + .content3{
 color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="topic" class="topic_selection, topic1" id="topic1">
<label for="topic1" class="content1">
<div class="contentbox" id="content1">
 <h1>Text 1</h1>
</div>
</label>
<input type="radio" name="topic" class="topic_selection" id="topic2">
<label for="topic2" class="content2">
<div class="contentbox" id="content2">
 <h1>Text2</h1>
</div>
</label>
<input type="radio" name="topic" class="topic_selection" id="topic3">
<label for="topic3" class="content3">
<div class="contentbox" id="content3">
 <h1>Text3</h1>
</div>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks, but used Aziz cause its quicker to change